# Would a small radio (RF) chip be able to communicate through a stainless steel tank?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, radio

My team is building a vacuum chamber out of stainless steel. We will be putting components into the chamber and recording temperature/pressure etc. values with an Arduino.

My question is whether we would be able to use a small RF module to transmit the values out of the tank so that we don't have to put a USB feedthrough.

I'm curious if the solid steel tank would act as a faraday cage or not, given that steel is a poor conductor of electricity. In theory is there any chance for the signal to permeate?

Comment: Magnetic coupling through the tank may also be viable.  I haven't actually done all the research on it, but by some quick searches, there's examples of using it to transmit power through metal barriers at 200Hz.

Comment: If you have a window, you might get out through that. If expecting to achieve high vacuum (say 1E-7 Torr or better) you will be disappointed since the board will outgas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider

- What is the frequency of the RF signal?
- What is the resistivity of the steel the tank is made of?
- What is the magnetic permeability of the steel the tank is made of?
- From the frequency, resistivity, and permeability, what is the skin depth of this signal in this material?
- What is the thickness of the tank wall?

If the tank wall is more than 2x the skin depth, then you won't get much signal at all through the wall directly.

Using a "typical" value of $69\ \mu\Omega\cdot{ cm}$ for the resistivity of stainless steel, and an RF frequency of 433 MHz (the lowest typical frequency for simple RF communication modules), [this skin depth calculator](https://www.pasternack.com/t-calculator-skin-depth.aspx) gives a skin depth of $20\ \mu m$. If the steel involved had a relatively high magnetic permeability (the permeability of stainless varies pretty widely) this value would be lower. If your operating frequency is higher, the skin depth will be lower. So if your tank wall thickness is even 0.5 mm, you'r not likely getting a signal through it.

If there are seams or gaps in the chamber wall where other wires or plumbing is routed through it, you might be able to get a signal through there, but it would depend a lot on the geometry of those gaps  (you'd want a seam with its long dimension at least 1/4 the wavelength of the RF signal).